# How to find the missing coordinate?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems, education

I have been given two points $P(0,1,3)$ & $Q(-1,5,2)$, both of them crosses a line in space. The third point is supposed to cross the line, but there is a missing coordinate $R(m,9,1)$. How do I find that missing coordinate ?

$l(x,y,z) = (0,1,3) + t(-1,4,-1)$

Thank you!

Comment: usually when there is an unknown to find, you need to write an equation to solve.

Comment: I mean, after I've found the line equation

$l(x,y,z) = <0,1,3>+t(-1,4,-1)$

Comment: The left side of the equation should be $R$.  Write the line equation as three separate equations, one in each coordinate.  Use one of the last two to evaluate $t$, then the first to evaluate $m$.

Comment: Thank you Ross!

Answer (score 0):

Your equation $(x,y,z) = (0,1,3) + t(-1,4,-1)$ can be viewed as three equations:

$$ x = 0 - t,$$

$$ y = 1 + 4t,$$

$$ z = 3 - t.$$

But you know your target:

$$ m = 0 - t,$$

$$ 9 = 1 + 4t,$$

$$ 1 = 3 - t.$$

Comment: Thank you very much!